# How to add O.DataType in request with Microsoft Graph API SDK?

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to use the Graph API to get information about user's permissions. I'm able to retrieve everything I want in a good format on the graph explorer using this request:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{{UserId}}/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$select=displayName,description](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%7B%7BUserId%7D%7D/transitiveMemberOf/microsoft.graph.group?$select=displayName,description)

However I don't know how to translate the /microsoft.graph.group in a Graph API SDK request. This is what I have now:

```
await this._graphServiceClient.Users[userId].TransitiveMemberOf.Request().Select(this.GetQuery()).GetAsync();
```

Is there a way to specify I only want the groups as OdataType?

I know I could filter on this type once the request is done, but if I don't have to do this it is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no support for OData casting in Graph API dotnet sdk but some inspiration how to append `microsoft.graph.group` to request url can be found in [msgraph-sdk-dotnet-contrib](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-contrib/blob/master/src/Extensions/BaseRequestBuilderExtensions.cs) repository.

There is a `WithODataCastMethod` which applies an OData cast filter to the returned collection.

Example of usage of that method

```
await this._graphServiceClient.Users[userId]
    .TransitiveMemberOf
    .WithODataCastMethod("microsoft.graph.group")
    .Request()
    .Select(this.GetQuery())
    .GetAsync();
```

Comment: I don't really what this does to the object. It return in the Current page some DirectoryObject and then I need to go look in the additionnal Data to find what I want. Without the ODataCast, it returns all type of odataType, but I think it is just easier to do a check about ```objectReturned is Group``` and then do some logic with the casted group object.